# What could be generating the compiler error in this statement to advance an iterator?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The following line generates a compiler error:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator blah = std::advance(instructions.begin(), x );
```

where I have declared:

```
std::vector<int> instructions;
int x;
```

The error I get is:

> `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'.`

What element of that statement is of type `void`?

Comment: Oh man - I'm sorry that my initially flawed answer caused you to have to do this...  I owe you a pint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking this up, I'm guessing the `advance` function returns void, which you are assigning to `blah`

try: `advance(blah, x);`, assuming of course you've initialized blah: `blah = instructions.begin();`

Answer (score 5):

advance does not return the advanced iterator, it moves the iterator that's passed as a parameter. So your code should read:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator blah = instructions.begin();
advance(blah, x);
```

Comment: @GMan:but you still beat me by 2! :-)

Comment: And the reason for this, in case anyone cares, is so that it works on Input Iterators, which can't (necessarily) be copied.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of advance is void and not an `vector<int>::iterator`.  It instead takes the first parameter by reference and advances it.

- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/advance.html

Answer (score 1):

`std::advance` doesn't return an iterator -- you need to use it more like:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator blah = instructions.begin();
advance(blah, x);
```

Or, since vector has random access iterators anyway:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator blah = instructions.begin()+x;
```

Answer (score 1):

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/) tells me that `std::advance` returns `void`, hence the problem.